# Open a console in firefox using python selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, firefox, console

I'm trying to open firefox console through Selenium with Python. Is it possible to send keys to the driver or something like that?

code:

```
import time
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

display = Display()
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.wikihow.com/Take-a-Screenshot-on-Firefox')
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.     
SHIFT + 'k')
browser.execute_script('window.devicePixelRatio=1;')
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Where do you want to send the keys, the search bar?

Comment: Actually, manually we will try to open the console using control + shift + k in firefox. So we are trying this manual process using selenium and then we need to pass few parameters to console as ":screenshot --fullpage --dpr 1".

Comment: Adding few points to above comment we are trying above code in the following versions
Firefox: 64.0
Selenium: 3.141.0
geckodriver: 0.23.0

Comment: @MayankMehtani We tried above code in 62 version also. But it is not working.
selenium version: 3.12.0, geckodriver version is 0.17.0.